# Ratio distribution of variance-gamma distribution and normal distribution

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, density-function, gamma-distribution, ratio

How does one calculate the probability density function of a random variable $Z$, defined as the ratio distribution of a variance-gamma distribution $X$ and a normal distribution $Y$ i.e. $Z=X/Y$?

The pdf of the variance-gamma distribution is defined by $f(x_{12})$ here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wishart_distribution#Marginal_distribution_of_matrix_elements

as $f(x)=\frac{|x|^{\frac{n-1}{2}}}{\Gamma (\frac{n}{2})\sqrt{2^{n-1}\pi(1-\rho^2)(\sigma_1 \sigma_2})^{n+1}}K_{\frac{n-1}{2}}\left(\frac{|x|}{\sigma_1 \sigma_2 (1-\rho^2)}\right)exp\left(\frac{\rho x}{\sigma_1 \sigma_2 (1-\rho^2)} \right)$

Does anyone know any sources/references on how to do this? I've tried calculating it by hand using the formula $p_z(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |y|p_{X,Y}(zy,y)dy$, as recommended [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution#Derivation), and found the process did not converge to a solution. But, my maths is not too great so I don't want to give up yet.

Comment: You can always check in [Gradshteyn and Ryzhik](http://fisica.ciens.ucv.ve/~svincenz/TISPISGIMR.pdf). For instance in 6.61.

Comment: Thanks for your help Xi'an, that's a really useful document